# Top Cells in my UItableView does not appear

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

Here is my question:

I have uitableview with different sections and each section have many rows.

The problem is that when I run the app in iPad simulator my first five rows of section 0 in the UITableView does not appear unless I scroll up to see them then they get back to be not appeared after stop scrolling ?

PLEASE HELP .
Thanks in advance and happy coding.

Here is the implementation of Datasource Methods:1. number of sections:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        // Return the number of sections.
        NSMutableArray *catarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        catarr= [d Category];
        NSInteger length ;

        length = [catarr count];

        return length;
    }
```

2.number of rows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    NSMutableArray *catarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    catarr = [d Category];
    NSInteger length ;
    length = [catarr count];
    NSInteger count ;
    NSMutableArray *word;

    for ( int i=0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {
        if (section == i )
        {
            NSString *str = [catarr objectAtIndex:i];
            word = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            word = [d CatRowName:str];
            count = [word count];
            return count;
        }
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

3. cell at index path :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifer = @"Cell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell= [ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer]; 
    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    UILabel *label ;

    label=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSString *value = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    label.text = value;
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;


    label=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    NSString *value2 = [[mainArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    label.text= value2;


NSString *value3 = [[mainArray3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:value3];
    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Can you include your code for all of the `UITableViewDataSource` methods?

Comment: What was self.tblcell in your previously posted code and how is it being used?

Comment: Ok I will add them now . @jszumski

Comment: @jszumski i posted the method could you help please ?

Comment: @Wain I posted my methods could you help please ?

Comment: What is [d Category]?

Comment: You need to stop creating new instances and then throwing them away (if not using ARC this is very leaky code, if you are it's just very wasteful).

Comment: Replace the for loop with 'NSString *str = [catarr objectAtIndex:section];,

Comment: And why do you have different objects being used to calculate the number of sections and rows than to populate the rows with content? This is very convoluted code...

Comment: @Wain THANK YOU THIS IS VALUABLE COMMENTS . But my problem is still there .

Comment: Please update your question with your new cleaner code, details of your data model and any other table view methods you have implemented. Also, when you say the rows don't appear, you mean they have no text? Also, looking at your code again, what levels are you trying to access on the UITableViewCell (do they really exist??)